# Sending NSDictionary as a JSON parameter in a POST API

Tags: ios, json, http-post

I have a POST API that I want to use with my App. Its required parameters look something like this:

```
parameter/type/field option/sample

id  /  int  /  required  /  33
products  /  json/  required/  [{"id":"PREPAY_22223","quantity":1}]
card  /  string  /  option  /  123456
```

Using JSONModel, I am trying to POST my data with this method:

```
- (RACSignal *)discount:(NSString *)planID withProducts:(NSArray *)product withCardf6:(NSString*)cardf6{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [self defaultParameters];
    parameters[@"id"] = @(planID.intValue);
    ProductJSON *p = [[EZProductJSON alloc]initWithDictionary:product[0] error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:p, nil];
    parameters[@"products"] = array;
    parameters[@"card"] = cardf6;
    parameters[@"local"] = @"en_US";

return [[[self rac_POST:@"plan/discount" parameters:parameters] map:^id(RACTuple *t) {
    return t;
}] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
        return [self customErrorSignal:error];
}];
}
```

I keep getting an error that tells me I am using the invalid product data. I am not sure why. Should I just be sending in a NSDictionary instead of a JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to JSON string using :

```
NSArray *myArray;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And pass `jsonString` to API parameter...

Like this :

```
- (RACSignal *)discount:(NSString *)planID withProducts:(NSArray *)product withCardf6:(NSString*)cardf6{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [self defaultParameters];
    parameters[@"id"] = @(planID.intValue);
    ProductJSON *p = [[EZProductJSON alloc]initWithDictionary:product[0] error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:p, nil];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    parameters[@"products"] = array;
    parameters[@"card"] = cardf6;
    parameters[@"local"] = @"en_US";

return [[[self rac_POST:@"plan/discount" parameters:parameters] map:^id(RACTuple *t) {
    return t;
}] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
        return [self customErrorSignal:error];
}];
}
```

Hope this will help you out.....

Comment: should it be parameters[@"products"] = jsonString; ?